# Magento 2 Frontend panel not working after ssl

Tags: magento2.3, https, http-status-403

In the backend, I've enabled Use Secure URLs in the Frontend and I changed all the setting but my site is not working.

see below screenshot:

[image]

Comment: your change **`core_config_data`** table base_url with https ? If Yes, you change remove **`var/cache`** and  **`var/view_preprocessed`**

Comment: I did but it’s not working.

Comment: Have you change the URL into the database?

Comment: Do you have an ssl certificate configured for the domain you are using?